# Multiline tooltip using only React

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs

I'm trying to build a multiline tooltip using [[this example]](https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-make-an-extremely-reusable-tooltip-component-with-react-and-nothing-else-7opo3?from-embed=&file=/src/App.js:250-489), I'm using it as a refernce because it involves functional components.
It works just fine, when its a short line of text, but doesn't go on a new line, which is something that I need.

I tried adding < /br > inside of the content, changing the content to jsx format and adding code below to the css file:

```css
  width: 200px;
  word-wrap: break-word;
```

All it managed to do was decrease the tooltip backgronud width to 200px.

How do I change code in the example to go on a new line if content size width is going above the predetermined width?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How do I change code in the example to go on a new line if content size width is going above the predetermined width?

Besides setting the `width` to the e.g. `200px`, you should also remove the `white-space: nowrap;` property because that is simply disallowing the text to break, even if it does overflow the container.

Codesandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/how-to-make-an-extremely-reusable-tooltip-component-with-react-and-nothing-else-forked-v09e4y

More info about `white-space` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/white-space

Comment: Thanks alot kind user! Completely overlooked that property